# Trix-editor on change event not working

Tags: javascript, html, events, reactjs, rich-text-editor

From couple of days,I am struggling to get **tirx-change** event fired when [trix-editor's](https://github.com/basecamp/trix) content changes.But not able to figure out the issue.I am using react js for view.
Below is my code :

```
class Desc extends React.Component {   
 handleChangeTrix(event){this.setState({[event.target.description.name]:
    event.target.description.value});
        }
    render(){
      return(
   <div className="container-fluid">
       <form  onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} 
              className="form-horizontal" >
         <input id="description"
                 name="description"
                 className="form-control"
                 value={this.state.description} 
                 hidden="True" type="hidden">
         </input>
        <trix-editor trix-change={this.handleChangeTrix.bind(this)}
                     classname="trix-content"
                     input="description" 
                     placeholder="Start typing here...." >
    </trix-editor>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
   </form>
</div>);
    }
}
```

If you feel some details are missing please ask in comment.If you feel question is inappropriate and deserve a down vote,i would love to know mistake via your valueable comment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never worked with Trix Editor, but your code seems to be invalid. Do you have errors in your browser console?

Comment: maybeb you need to put `input`, `trix-editor` element in form tag. Because `render` function only return one div. I think so.

Comment: hi,this is not the complete code(actual one is too lengthy). i just took required line and framed it here.May be because of that some parenthesis missed out.could you please tell the issue more specifically. i will try to improve the above snippet.
I am not getting any error in browser console.

Comment: @DangCongCong it is there in form tag only. i will modify code to give clear picture.
thanks.

Comment: I have updated question.i believe it will make issue more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you call setState was wrong. It should be changed to

```
handleChangeTrix(event){this.setState({description:
event.target.description.value});
```